# Angular Select control ngFor is not working in table with results

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ngfor

I have this dataset for a table:

[image]

I'm trying to populate a select control as part of html table with results.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="PricingTemplatesList">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Margin Template</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer">
                <select id="pricingtemplates">
                    <option [ngValue]="pricingTemplate.Oid" *ngFor="let pricingTemplate of customer.PricingTemplatesList">{{pricingTemplate.Name}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

The result I'm getting is blank select control.

This is how the list items look like:

[image]

I'm even trying this {{customer.PricingTemplatesList.length}} to see if the items exist but I'm getting undefined, although when doing console.log(customer) as you can see I'm able to see the data.

Is there anything specific I need to do?

Comment: `pricingTemplate.Name` is wrong, as there is no property with `Name` it should be `pricingTemplate.name`

Comment: thx I corrected that but still the same, the select control doesn't have any items. Do you see any other issue?

Comment: In which object this dataset belongs? or `PricingTanplateList` a variable directly in your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correction in your code . Use below code .

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="PricingTemplatesList">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Margin Template</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer">
                <select id="pricingtemplates">
                    <option [ngValue]="pricingTemplate.Oid" *ngFor="let pricingTemplate of customer.pricingTemplatesList">{{pricingTemplate.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Replace pricingTemplate.Name with pricingTemplate.name .

And also replace in `*ngFor` `customer.PricingTemplatesList` with `customer.pricingTemplatesList` (capital P to lowerCase P).